# Display metatag description of nodes in taxonomy term views

Tags: views, 9, meta-tags

In Taxonomy term views, where are displayed shorten nodes I want to display node's metatag description instead body summary, but it doesn't work.
I'm using [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module with it's submodule Metatag: Views.
Views looks like this:
[image: Metatag field in views]
Please help

Comment: IMO you're looking at this the wrong way round - if you need an alternate description for the node, that should be in a field, where it can be accessed natively using Views and other parts of the system. Then it's a simple matter of changing the description metatag to the token for that field, and you have a robust solution

Comment: But I already have filed in metatag description of node, it is not solution to duplicate that field in new one. Is there any way to access it in Views?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend duplicating it, rather moving it from the metatag field into its own field and referencing it. If the data belongs to the node, keep it in the node. Only keep it in the metatags field if it's strictly only being used as meta data. But to answer your question: no, I don't believe the metatags module makes that level of granular data available to Views. It's not impossible to do so, but would require code

Comment: See this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/3027873, the patch in #7 is reported to work and would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU [Clive](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive). I implement patch from this two files, this [MetatagViewsFormatter.php](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-10-28/expose_metatag_views_field-3027873-17.patch) and this [MetatagFormatter.php](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-27/expose_metatag_views_field-3027873-7.patch) from here [Provide field formatter to output meta tags on-page, e.g. for use with Views (D9)](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/3027873) and it works!
Now I have in views metatag field this options:

[image: metatag values including description]